# Python and Tkinter: How to set a StringVar from a different class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I´m studying some python and tkinter, and tried a very simple sample app.

A tkinter GUI, a label that displays text, and 2 buttons bellow.
These buttons where supposed to change the text in the label, as it is linked to a StringVar through textvariable param...

What should happen, simply:
Press "A" button and "A" will be shown at the label
Press "B" button and "B" will be shown at the label

But when I press button "A" the program gives me NameError: name 'display_frame' is not defined.

Cant figure out what´s happening. I´m accessing the object attribute...

obs: as button A is problematic, not tried configure the function for button B

```py
import tkinter

class TkinterWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='orange')



class DisplayFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='cyan')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')

        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set('Hello')
        self.display = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.text, font=15, bg="#bebebe", relief="groove", bd=5, height=5 )
        self.display.grid(sticky='nsew')

class ButtonsFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='green')
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_A = tkinter.Button(self, text='A', command=self.write_A)
        self.button_A.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_B = tkinter.Button(self, text='B')
        self.button_B.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, sticky='nsew')

    def write_A(self):
        display_frame.text.set('A')


def main():
    window = TkinterWindow()
    display_frame = DisplayFrame(window)
    buttons_frame = ButtonsFrame(window)
    window.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: If you globalise `display_frame ` then it'll work but this is not the recommended approach. The proper way to do this is to establish a connection between `DisplayFrame` and `ButtonsFrame` to access each other's attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you are having is the class attribute `self.text` is not visible to the other classes. One way to fix this is to move that variable to the main tk class and then just reference it. This is the quickest fix to your code.

```
import tkinter

class TkinterWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='orange')
        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set('Hello')


class DisplayFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='cyan')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')


        self.display = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.master.text, font=15, bg="#bebebe", relief="groove", bd=5, height=5 )
        self.display.grid(sticky='nsew')

class ButtonsFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='green')
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_A = tkinter.Button(self, text='A', command=self.write_A)
        self.button_A.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_B = tkinter.Button(self, text='B')
        self.button_B.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, sticky='nsew')

    def write_A(self):
        self.master.text.set('A')


def main():
    window = TkinterWindow()
    display_frame = DisplayFrame(window)
    buttons_frame = ButtonsFrame(window)
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

That said you have a few things in your code you should be mindful of. Over use of `self.` when it is not needed and applying the geometry manage inside the frame class is a bad idea as well.

Personally I would have built this all in one class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class TkinterWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='orange')

        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set('Hello')

        display_frame = tk.Frame(self, background='cyan')
        ButtonsFrame = tk.Frame(self, background='green')
        display_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        display_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ButtonsFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ButtonsFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ButtonsFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        display_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')
        ButtonsFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Label(display_frame, textvariable=self.text, font=15,
                 bg="#bebebe", relief="groove", bd=5).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Button(ButtonsFrame, text='A',
                  command=lambda: self.update_text('A')).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(ButtonsFrame, text='B',
                  command=lambda: self.update_text('B')).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, sticky='nsew')

    def update_text(self, value):
        self.text.set(value)

TkinterWindow().mainloop()
```

Comment: > the main issue you are having is the class attribute self.text is not visible to the other classes.  I´m a little confused about this... am I not accessing the self.text through the object?

Comment: >  applying the geometry manage inside the frame class is a bad idea as well.  Ok, what is the wrong stuff about this and where to apply grid management code?

Comment: @BrunoLemos Inside of your example `display_frame` is not in the global namespace and is only in the local namespace of function `main`. Because of this nothing outside of when your method `write_A` tries to find `display_frame` it first looks locally in `write_A` and because it did not find it there it then checks global and also does not find it there. You can actually test this by moving your code in main to the global namespace and it should work there.

Comment: @BrunoLemos As for the geometry issues take this example. If I decide to use `pack()` on something and then try to use your frame class it will cause the code to error out. In this particular example its not hurting right now but its bad practices and will likely cause errors for you down the road.

Comment: " would have built this all in one class." my idea was make it readable... easy to find and organized stuff... Are not? Are most of codes and programs a great singleton file and I have a wrong concept about fancy organization?

Comment: @BrunoLemos It depends on how you look at readability. But yes I would say for larger apps separating out big complex frames will help with troubleshooting and readability. For smaller apps you can reduce the complexity and keep things clean and short without sacrificing readability. Your approach is just fine as far as the classes are concerned. That is why I said `personally`.

Comment: wich are the uneeded self´s?

Comment: @BrunoLemos your buttons and your labels do not need to be a class attribute or even be assigned to a variable name. If you look at my 2nd example you will see I do not name the buttons or labels and they work fine. Keep in mind the only reason to use `self.` is to reference a class attribute/method. So If you do not need to change your buttons in any way later you do not need to use the `self.` prefix.

Comment: I´m confused.... when you say that self refers to a class attribute or method... shouldn´t be an instance attribute/method?

Comment: Still about my usage of geometry manage inside the frame class... let me se if I got it right: as my intention is the reuse of the frame, the person who is going to take it should be the responsible for placing it, however my code already places it. Right?

Comment: @BrunoLemos but if someone wants to use `pack()` in the same container you are putting your frame in it will error out. So the placement should be done outside of the frame class to provide better flexibility to use any geometry manager you want for your overall code.